# Disable element from beeing detect on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, position, absolute

I have a simple button element.Then right after that I have a badge that i positioned on top of the button with position absolute. Normaly when you hover over a btn-dark from bootstrap it sligthly changes the color to grey and it works fine but when i hover the mouse over the badge that is placed on top of the button, the hover effect stops working becasue it counts as hovering out of the button. Is there anyway to keep the hovering effect on without any javascript? Is there anyway to make the badge undetectable on hovering somehow?[image]

```
<div>                
    <a href="#">
        <i class=" btn btn-dark cart-button fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger badge-style"> 
            {{cartcounter}} 
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the hover effects to the parent element that way anything inside of it will be affected by the properties. In this case the a tag is the parent. Give it a class and then the hover pseudo element. Something like:

```
<a class='parent-btn'>your button and badge </a>
```

Then in your css something like:

```
.parent-btn:hover { 
    filter: brightness(1.2) 
}
```